.postgresql file
I have a .postgresql file and I can't open it or import it into pgadmin4. Even if I change the extension to .sql.
Has anyone here worked with such a file?
I tried to open it with sublime text and notepad++, but only numbers were displayed.
pgadmin doesn't recognise the file.

Ask the person you got the file from. .postgresql isn't a common file extension AFAIK.

Numbers as in something like this?: 5047 444d 5001 0f00 0408 0101 0001 0000. If so I would bet the the file is the output of pg_dump, most likely the -Fc format. You will need to verify that before you go any further.

Yes, indeed, the figures seem to be like that.

You have not said where you got the file from and whether you can contact the source to find out how they created it.

I was finally able to open the file with pganim, in the ‘restore’ section. The problem was obviously linked to the file's large size.
